# How to animate UV mask position in Blender Render?

Tags: animation, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to create an animation of a rising sun. I know it's easier to just make a whole object moving, but for a specific reasons I can't take this approach.

What I'm trying to achieve is to change UV mask Y position in time using keyframes. So I tried pressing <kbd>i</kbd>  button with mouse hovering a proper value, but what I get is a warning:

`Button doesn't appear to have any property information attached (ptr.data = 000000000000, prop = 00000000000)`

I think this printscreen might be a better explaination:

[image]

Comment: You can't keyframe the UV island's location, but you can add keyframes to node parameters. Try the "Mapping" node in the node editor. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/nodes/types/vector/mapping.html

Comment: @FFeller, you can animate the islands location with the addon that's included with blender, called the AnimAll addon.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more research and thanks to @FFeller comment to my question I figured out that animating UV island's location is not possible. Besides of using a mapping node, I've found a simpler solution.

When all you need is animating UV island's location, you can animate UV Map offset instead. The property can be found in texture tab of the texture that should be animated.

[image]

Comment: actually, like I replied to FFeller, you can animate the uv island position. :)

Comment: Thats not an island, it's the whole UV.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing, You have minimum three ways to transform UM map:

1. "Mapping" node in the node editor.
2. "Mapping" texture.
3. Use UVProject or UVWarp modifiers.